# Which will be better for API creation - RESTify or KOA.js

Tags: node.js, api, restify, koa

I am trying to create a REST service for an iOS application.

I am debating to which framework should I use (as I am also a bit new to Node.js).

I started by considering the following - Express, HAPI, RESTify, KOA.js (using KOALA maybe?) and ended up by debating between RESTify (because it seems to be really easy for creating API) and KOA.js (because it is the new standard which will replace Express)..

also I saw the spike of popularity KOA.js was given recently..

Can someone give me the answer to which will be better for me?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your specific needs.

- KOA comes all the way from Express, and is empowered by ES6 generator, all of which makes it super concise and, as I say, more *right*.
- RESTify is based on Express and is more mature at what it is designed to do: Constructing REST API.

I will be using KOA for a personal project, and be using RESTify at work for a job that must be done right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at [fortune.js](http://fortunejs.com),
It's a great start if you want to integrate [json api](http://jsonapi.org) especially if your client use ember.js.

Another popular solution is [loopback.io](http://loopback.io) that allow you to quickly develop and test your api with swagger and cli tools for quick generation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Koa because it has better error-handling and stream-handling than express. Koa middleware is much simpler and less hacky than Express middleware due to the way middleware flows in a stack-like manner.
see this blog when you have 10000 request, koa performs better than express: https://www.appneta.com/blog/basic-performance-comparison-between-koa-and-express/